# Which database to use for structured - high volume - insert+read+summerize data?

Tags: database, nosql, data-mining, data-warehouse

Requirements are as follows :

- High volume, structured, real time data.
- data is insert only (no  updates)
- Data needs to be summarized- real time.
- data needs to be analyzed - real-time.
- Transactions wont matter (since data is read-only)
- data structure will not be modified frequently. (almost never)

To elaborate a little more...Data is generated by a software...One user can have many instance of this software and our system supports multiple users.

Our System >>  Users >> their software (all relations are one to many - left to right)

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, the only way to do **real-time** is to not store it at all beyond maybe writing it to a dated log file for recovery. Use **stream processing** for the analysis, not a database.

Comment: So what do you suggest ? Something like scribe ?

Comment: i have something like this in my mind...scribe for collecting log. hadoop for storing summaries (which we need for later use). (Honest confession - don't know any of them...i derived these from some presentations and reading...)

Answer (score 1):

For Data storage , use [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) HDFS (Hadoop File system)

If data is insert only (data structure not getting modified) , use [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/)

Use [Sqoop](http://incubator.apache.org/sqoop/) as a connector between HDFS and Hive.

If data needs to be search ( something like Search engine ) , use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Lastly for maintaining log data, try [Flume](https://cwiki.apache.org/FLUME/)